# Merge objects with the same property

Tags: javascript, axios

I need to merge two objects by their properties. In my objects, the properties look like this 2023-06-05. As an example, each object has a property with a date and then either a file or folder property.
Ultimately.

What I expect:

```
recent: {
    2023-05-06: {
            files: Array(),
            folders: Array(),
            },
    2023-05-07: {
            files: Array(),
            folders: Array(),
            },
}
```

How can I do it?

```
created() {
        axios.get('/api/file/recent').then(r => {
            var temp = new Array();
            var sorted = [];
            temp['files'] = r.data.files;
            temp['folders'] = r.data.folder;
            var temp_files = temp['files'].reduce((a,b) => {
                a[b.created_at] = a[b.created_at]  ? a[b.created_at].concat(b) : [b];
                return a;
            }, {});
            var temp_folders = temp['folders'].reduce((a,b) => {
                a[b.created_at] = a[b.created_at] ? a[b.created_at].concat(b) : [b];
                return a;
            }, {});

            var files = new Object();
            var folders = new Object();
            Object.keys(temp_files).forEach(key => {
                files[key] = {files: temp_files[key]};
            })
            Object.keys(temp_folders).forEach(key => {
                folders[key] = {folders: temp_folders[key]};
            })
```

[var files, var folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4BZu.png)

Comment: `2023-05-06: {` ? You mean `"2023-05-06": {`

Answer (score 0):

I found solution

```
var recent = [];
var keys = Object.keys(temp_files,temp_folders);
keys.forEach(key => {
          recent[key] = {files: files[key] ? files[key] : null, folders: folders[key] ? folders[key] : null
          };
})
```

But now i want to see better solution, because mine looks awful i guess